# excel spread sheet not taking the desired value

Tags: excel

i have one excel sheet it is of .xlxs. i want to write one value that is

> 11506928485335397944093182820235

in the excel sheet but it showing something like

> 1.15069284853353E+31

. how to enter the same value.

Comment: Do you fill the cell via a program or you just type the number in the Excel sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways:

Place a single quote at the beginning:

'11506928485335397944093182820235

or

format the cell as text before making any entries.

or

with VBA *(using cell **B9** as an example)*:

```
Sub UseVBA()
    With Range("B9")
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = "11506928485335397944093182820235"
        .ClearFormats
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

The last option is not available if your file format is ***.xlsx***

Comment: This approach may assign the cell as text instead of number, for example, whose default adjustment is left-adjust.

Comment: @YingyuYOU  **You are correct!**  It WILL assign the cell as *Text*, but *Text* is the best you can do with a string of 32 numerals.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia,

> Excel calculates in double-precision floating-point format from the IEEE 754 specification... Although Excel can display 30 decimal places, its precision for a specified number is confined to 15 significant figures.

1.15069284853353E+31 has exactly 15 significant figures.

EDIT: P.S. Even by specifying the format string of the cell as `################################` (32 sharp characters, `#`), the value shown is `11506928485335300000000000000000`, you can see there is only 15 significant figures, others are all trailing zeroes.

See also:
1. [Numeric precision in Microsoft Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel)
2. [Understanding Floating Point Precision, aka “Why does Excel Give Me Seemingly Wrong Answers?”](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/)